# CSS conic-gradient with transparent center?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 45px 0;
}

.circular-bar {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background: conic-gradient(black 0deg, #e8f0f7 0deg);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.circular-bar::before {
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;   
    width: 60px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="circular-bar">

    </div>
</div>
```

but I'd like to make the center of the wrapper div transparent. Do I have to take another approach, or is it possible to set the center of the conic-gradient to transparent?

Comment: No, I don't believe that you can have a transparent center with a conic gradient.